# "Броня" и "бронь"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Слова "броня" и "бронь" однокоренные, да? Но для чего было менять окончание для обозначения резервирования чего-либо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос несколько странно звучит. "Для чего" предполагает какую-то намеренную линию действий. Но такое в языке бывает крайне редко. Так уж сложилось, без чьей-либо субъективной воли.

Теперь по сути того, что можно вообще сказть об этих словах.
"Бронь" признаёт нормативным только Кузнецов. Остальные словари в этом значении (закрепление, резервирование) предлагают брОня.
Ну а бронЯ - защитная обшивка или оболочка (технически модет иметь массу вариантов конструкции).

Видимо, последний вариант более молодой и возник с появлением броненосной техники (впервые - на флоте в XIX веке). Возможно даже, что эти значения проникли в язык разными путями. Во всяком случае нет тничего удивительного, что произношение разошлось.

Comment: Слово "БрОня" знаю, но НИ разу не слышала его в речи. Всегда только "бронь": и в устной речи, и во всяких объявлениях на вокзальных кассах тоже.

Comment: Я слышал "брОню" в семье. И не только "тётю Броню", но и то, что мы обсуждаем. Бронь воспринмиаю как что-то инородное.

Comment: Вы коренной москвич?

Comment: Что считать "коренным"? Наверное нет, не коренной. В третьем поколении по материнской бабке. Она из Питера, из "полудворянской" семьи.
В любом случае, это не та бабка, от которой я таких слов нахватался.
Дед по отцу - генерал, брОня - это оттуда.

Comment: О! Для меня самый что ни на есть коренной. Нормы произношения и ударения впитывались с детства. Сахалин, Приморье- сюда ехали со всей страны. Много украинцев. Очень много из Мордовии. Если в овладении лексикой, грамматикой помогла книги, то что касается произношения и ударения  - столько пришлось в свое время переучивать!